# Get 401 response when using the authentication setup with the application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have created a service which can save a new user into database and (is supposed to) authenticate user. 
The problem I have right now is that I cannot authenticate my user with the same username and password after I have created with the service.

Authentication: Basic Auth 
Password encoder: BCryptPasswordEncoder
Database: local Mongodb

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder encoder;

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/config", "/registerUser").permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic()
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()


    ;
}

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
//authentication will work if I switch to the in-memory authentication below
//        authManagerBuilder
//                .inMemoryAuthentication()
//                .withUser("user").password(encoder.encode("password")).roles("USER");

    authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(this.encoder);
    return authProvider;
}

}



@Service
public class UserService implements IUserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailRepository userDetailRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Override
    public User saveUser(User user) {
        String password = user.getPassword();
        String passwordHased = this.encoder.encode(password);
        user.setPassword(passwordHased);
        User ud = this.userDetailRepository.save(user);
        return ud;
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserWithId(String userId) {
        return this.userDetailRepository.findById(userId).get();
    }

    @Override
    public User loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return this.userDetailRepository.findByUsername(s);
    }
}



public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    private String userId;

    private String username;

    private String password;


    @Override
    public final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<String> privileges = new ArrayList<>();
        privileges.add("READ");
        privileges.add("WRITE");
        return getGrantedAuthorities(privileges);
    }
    private final List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(final List<String> privileges) {
        final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (final String privilege : privileges) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(privilege));
        }
        return authorities;
    }


... (other overridden methods omitted)

}
```

I am suspecting my getAuthorities() method is not doing correctly.

Please let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question.

There is nothing wrong with the code I posted above but what I omitted to post. In my User class, which extends UserDetails, there are a few methods required to override.

```
  @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
```

They are now all set return true and it works, previously they all returned false..

silly mistake.